# How does this Chinese phrase translates back to English?

Tags: translation, social-media

This had been news for a while now.

We've had reports on TV and net blogs about inappropriate videos known as "儿童邪典" which translates literally to "children evil compendium". These videos depicts inappropriate adult content using well-known children cartoon characters.

According to the reports, western video sharing and social media sites such as YouTube and Facebook also had faced similar problems, and "now these videos are penetrating the Chinese Internet".

So what I'm deadly curious about, is what had these types of videos been called in English, do they have a shorter name, when they're reported in English media, and if possible, the historical background of what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Elsagate" is a new term coined to refer to this phenomenon. It's a combination of "Watergate" to indicate a scandal (referring to US President Nixon's political scandal that caused him to resign) and Elsa - the main character in the animated "Frozen" film.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there was ever a specific name for this which became common-place. Everyone had their own variation of a name. So, for example, in the UK, some parents would keep what is known as a 'naughty book' for their children. Essentially, if a child is naughty, then the parent would write that in the 'naughty book' and - at the end of the week - the parent would decide how much pocket money to give the child 根据 the number of entries in the naughty book for that week. (Previously, I imagine smacking was involved, but that is now frowned upon and is possibly illegal). This concept is also known as the misdemeanor book, or similar.

As such, the videos which work the other way around (i.e. the adult is being told off) would have a name which plays on this concept. Ones which I have heard include "Parent Naughty Book Videos" or "Adult Naughty Book Videos" or "Parent Misbehaviour Videos". "Parent" is more common than "Adult" in these names, as Adult can sometimes imply pornographic content (Adult video, Adult shop), not to be confused with the non-sexual meaning of "Adult", e.g. Adult College, which is a college for adults, not a sex-school!
Hope this helps!